# Python & Django web app how to delete database values without affecting reports

Tags: python, django, database

I had a web app developed that is a simple crm used to create estimates, service reports and invoices. It includes a module for tracking inventory.

I found if I deleted an item from inventory that the estimates, service reports and invoices that include this item will fail to load and cause an error.

Is there a way to work around this? I am guessing it is referencing the id of the inventory item and then cannot find the details.

How can I delete inventory items without affecting existing reports?

The datbase file where the inventory is stored is named db.sqlite3

Comment: By using soft deletions instead of actually deleting the objects. This will likely require some reworking of your app's logic.

Comment: "soft deletion" is a way to say: store a field on the model to track whether it has been "deleted" or not. When you "delete" the row don't actually delete it from the db but update the field e.g. `deleted=true` or `status="DELETED"` or similar. Then in the rest of the code you can select rows which haven't been soft-deleted by filtering on that field.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what behavior do you want when you delete inventories. I'm assuming that you are using Django's `ForeignKey` field into your model.

Accordingly to [Django's Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete), you can have 7 major operations when you delete an instance of a model:

1. CASCADE: Cascade deletes, meaning that the report should be deleted as well.
2. PROTECT: Prevents deletion of the report, while raising ProtectedError exception.
3. RESTRICT: It is similar to PROTECT, but you can delete it if you also delete a different object in the same operation via CASCADE. The example given in the documentaton URL helps.
4. SET_NULL: The report still exists, and the value becomes NULL.
5. SET_DEFAULT: If the field has a default value, it returns to it.l
6. SET: Set the field to the value passed as argument to `SET`.
7. DO_NOTHING: Nothing happens.

Those are the second argument when you use `ForeignKey` such as:

```
# in Report model
inventory_item = models.ForeignKey(InventoryItem, models.CASCADE, ...) # using CASCADE as an example
```